# Was DC’s Adam Strange an influence on the creation of the TV program Doctor Who?

Tags: dc, doctor-who, influences

Back before *Doctor Who* began when the creators were thinking up the idea of The Doctor they thought first of  a scientist among other things. And DC’s Adam Strange was created not that long before *Doctor Who*.

Adam Strange’s cosmic inception was in 1958 and *Doctor Who* was created in 1963 that's only 4 years in difference.

Adam Strange rides on "zeta beams" and "dematerialization" in my opinion is a form of zeta beam in itself.

Was DC’s Adam Strange an influence on the creation of the TV program *Doctor Who* and the Doctor her/himself?

Also from the *Batman: The Brave and the Bold* series I got a *Doctor Who* vibe from Adam though I may be wrong of course.

Comment: I guess zeta beams are similar to dematerialization is all I can come up with

Comment: Interesting notion, but the evidence you are giving is very flimsy. Non-existant, really. I don't think this sort of question belongs here, really.

Answer (score 5):

Adam Strange: human archeologist from Earth accidentally teleported to an alien planet where he eventually became the love interest of the daughter of the scientist responsible for his teleportation in the first place.

The Doctor: None of those things.

So, yeah, I'd suggest possible influence was close to none, especially as *Doctor Who* was initially intended as an educational program about history and only later became the adventure series everyone now knows it as.

If anything, Adam Strange is an updated version of John Carter, especially the part where the hero is forced to return to Earth periodically but finds a way of getting back to the alien planet and his love interest.

Answer (score 1):

The evidence you give to suggest a link is extremely weak, so I have no qualms in saying *no*, it probably was not an influence on the creation of the show.

*Doctor Who* was, and still is, relentlessly British, so it seems unlikely that an American comic could have been a *major* influence on it. True, Sydney Newman, the Canadian-born TV executive who suggested the BBC produce *Doctor Who*, was a comic-book fan and was quoted as saying "Up to the age of 40, I don't think there was a science-fiction book I hadn't read". However, if you take that literally, it means he read comic books up until 1957 (he was born in 1917), one year before Adam Strange appeared. Sure, that doesn't mean he *didn't* read it, but he was also adamant that *Doctor Who* didn't have any "bug-eyed monsters" - that is, it wasn't to be like any other science-fiction set in space. Alien foes did eventually come, but they were deliberately excluded at its inception, which again would set it very much apart from the alien foes Adam Strange fought in early stories such as Kanjar Ro and Alva Xar.

The initial creation of the show was not just the work of one person, but of several people. Sydney Newman is often credited with the title of the show and the bare-bones concept; producer Verity Lambert is said to have had a huge influence on the show; but the first script-writer was Anthony Coburn (an Australian). This would exclude any single person's influence from pervading throughout the concept anyway.

If anything, early *Doctor Who* was influenced by the earlier BBC sci-fi horror *The Quatermass Experiment*, something which has frequently been suggested by show insiders. The show and its concept have been discussed and dissected so many times that if there were any other notable influences, they would surely have been mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

No, that's your answer, no *Doctor Who* is not based off of a comic book.

Comment: Whilst this is an answer to the question it is very unsubstantiated and could do with adding supporting evidence to it to back up your case with an [edit].